# Can I fix this Google thing that adds my Name to the results titles twice?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-plus

I am using Wordpress. I haven't installed any SEO plugin. Because titles created by the theme was ok and my site is a personal/artistic website.

Everything was one, search results would go like: **Site title - post title**. (Btw my website is in Persian, so they were Persian too as I wrote them)

But recently, the results contains my Latin name! I didn't add that anywhere!

Could you please tell me where does it come from and how am I suppose to remove/change that?

I read somewhere that this could be because of **Google+ profile** and the thing that Google has like **publisher** id or something. Could it affect the search result title?

They say when you add **your website link** into the Google+ Links section and then choose the exact email address to write on wordpress (or other services) Google automatically adds your name. But I thought it was only appeared on the description and not the title itself.

Another weird thing: I have a exactly **similar** website with the same version of Wordpress, same theme, same plugins, and it's fine!

The only difference was a **Google XML plugin** that I installed on my own site which I don't think can change the titles, can it??

And it does not appear on all results.

I want to know where that Latin name comes from and how to remove that.

Comment: Google can put whatever title they think is best for their users. They obviously feel having your latin name makes the pages from your site more searchable. You can't control this.

Comment: I'm sincerely hoping that you are joking :) You have eliminated the SEO industry, once for all.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons this is happening.

1. Google is now adding titles names if your title is too short on search results.
2. If people are searching and using the term, Google will append it to your site title.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. 1- I thought it was the case. But there are fewer titles that are just fine. And another site of mine with 2 word titles is ok as well. 2- I didn't know about this at all. Can we prevent it from happening? And I was on the website for almost 8 years and it never happened before.

Comment: Khahesh mikonam. Sadly there is no way to prevent it and it just happened to a few of my sites that have been online for just as long. I was going crazy at first thinking I had somehow accidentally enabled adding Site name to the Titles. I would assume for whatever reason they are advertising websites brand names as well. Whether this is good or bad, we will see. I do not like my content presented different from creation.

Comment: Oh one more thing, when you say you added an XML sitemap plugin.. did you submit that sitemap to Google via Webmaster Tools? If not you should do so and then have an HTML version on your site.

Comment: Sepas :) I am wondering about any relation between this and Google+ publisher thing. You know, it is exactly identical to my Google+ name (Shahab Siavash) and yet we all know how hard Google tries tp pin G+ on us on search results. Another annoying thing is my search results titles already had my name (in Persian) so now there is 2! Persian+Latin+Page title. I can not believe that I'm searching and asking on internet and there is no solution. Very weird indeed!

Comment: I added the xml to webmaster and for now it seems doing fine. Although I changed it to Jetpack Wordpress plugin XML, because then I thought there was a connection between the problem and Google XML plugin. I was (and am) hopeless!